# ICSharpCode.sharpziplib.zip.zipexception. Cannot find central directory

Tags: windows, files, troubleshooting, dll, library

Every time we run a certain commercial software in a Windows Server 2019 we get a pop-up window with this error:

```
ICSharpCode.sharpziplib.zip.zipexception. Cannot find central directory
```

It looks like the dll ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll is trying to unzip a corrupt file and then it throws this error.

The dll should be ok (it works in other servers) so we need to find the file that's causing the error.

We've tried Microsoft Process Monitor but we're getting +1M registers and we haven't been able to find anything relevant.

So the question is, is there a way to find which files are used/modified by a .dll? How would you approach this?

We've been trying to troubleshoot this for months and even official support has been unable to help... I hope this can help others with similar issues.

Regards

Josep

Comment: A DLL doesn't act on its own, it's called by some process. You should identify and monitor that process.